# How to compare 2 enum variables?

Tags: rust

Below is my code to compare 2 `enum` variables in Rust.

[I uploaded the code into playground here.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=df3ed2968182ccb6f124835f171e0b90).

Pretty straightforward, I just want to use equal operator (`==`) to compare both enum variable. Thank you in advance.

my enum:

```
use std::fmt::Display;

#[derive(Display)]
enum Fruits {
    Apple, 
    Orange,
}
// I try to use ToString but Rust cannot find derive macro `Display` in this scope
// ERROR: 
// doesn't satisfy `Fruits: ToString`
// doesn't satisfy `Fruits: std::fmt::Display`

// had to implement PartialEq for Fruits
impl PartialEq for Fruits {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.to_string() == other.to_string()
        // here, I'm trying to use string conversion to compare both enum
        // it displays an error: 
        // method cannot be called on `&Fruits` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    }
}
```

my main.rs:

```
fn main(){
    let a = Fruits::Apple;
    let b = Fruits::Orange;
    let c = Fruits::Apple;
    
    if a == c {
        println!("Correct! A equals with C !");
    }
    
    
     if a != b {
        println!("Correct! A is not equal with B !");
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't build then compare strings if you want to compare enum variants.

The simple solution to compare enum variants (and most structs) is to derive `PartialEq`:

```
#[derive(PartialEq)]
enum Fruits {
    Apple, 
    Orange,
}
fn main() {
    dbg!(Fruits::Apple == Fruits::Orange); // false
    dbg!(Fruits::Orange == Fruits::Orange); // true
}
```

Comment: Much simpler solution. I don't know if `#[derive(PartialEq)]` can be derived like this. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

How about deriving `Debug` instead of `Display`? Display cannot be derived.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Fruits {
    Apple, 
    Orange,
}

impl PartialEq for Fruits {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        format!("{:?}", self) == format!("{:?}", other)
    }
}

fn main(){
    let a = Fruits::Apple;
    let b = Fruits::Orange;
    let c = Fruits::Apple;
    
    if a == c {
        println!("Correct! A equals with C !");
    }
     if a != b {
        println!("Correct! A is not equal with B !");
    }
}
```

Comment: `format!("{:?}", self) == format!("{:?}", other)` works for me. But Is it OK for production though? Shouldn't it only used for debugging (hence the name Debug) only ?

Comment: I dont see any obvious problems with using it like this. I think it is OK.

Comment: I accept it as an answer but I'm curious if there are other way

Comment: For production, you probably don't want to compare string representation at all, but `#[derive(PartialEq)]` instead.

Comment: I agree and I totally forgot that PartialEq can be easily derived. You are right, of course.